# Can someone explain to me what's wrong with my code please?

Tags: c#, calculator

I've been learning C# and now I'm trying to create a calculator that reads your inputs to learn how to read inputs correctly. If it's really simple I'm sorry I'm new to this.
   The error says that it can't convert int to string on (10,20) and (14,20).

````
using System;

class Calculator {
static void Main() {
    int n1, n2;
    string operation;


    Console.Write("First number: ");
        n1 = int.Parse(Console.Read());
    Console.Write("Operation: ");
        operation = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Second number: ");
        n2 = int.Parse(Console.Read());

        if (operation == "+") {
            Console.Write(n1 + n2);
        }else if (operation == "-") {
            Console.Write(n1 - n2);
        }else if (operation == "*") {
            Console.Write(n1 * n2);
        }else if (operation == "/") {
            Console.Write(n1 / n2);
        };

    }
} ```
````

Comment: What input you are entering

Comment: `Console.Read()` returns an int value (the ASCII code of the key pressed).  `int.Parse()` expects `string` value as an argument an you are passing an int value (the result of `Console.Read()`). Change it to `Console.ReadLine()` and it has to be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with dot. 10.20 and 14.20.
Also try ReadLine

Answer (score 2):

Make all your calls `Console.ReadLine()` not `Console.Read()`

Make sure you type an integer for the operands. If you're not typing an integer (I couldn't decide if your `10,20` means your operands are ten and twenty or if you're from a country that uses comma as a decimal separator and 10,20 is ten-and-a-fifth) then you won't succeed in parsing a decimal number with int.Parse, try decimal.Parse instead and change all your data types

Using Console.Read() will read a single character and return its numeric value, so eg a 1 character has an int value of 31 (take a look at an ascii table) which will be very confusing, and even more confusing how A (ascii Value 65) can be added to B (66 - result 131) :) ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this as a starter for 10. There are ways to do it more efficiently I'm sure, but this should give you some ideas:

```
using System;

namespace Calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("First Number: ");
            int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Operation: ");
            string operation = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Second number: ");
            int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch(operation)
            {
                case "+":
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Result: {0}", (a + b)));
                    break;

                case "-":
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Result: {0}", (a - b)));
                    break;

                case "*":
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Result: {0}", (a * b)));
                    break;

                case "/":
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Result: {0}", (a / b)));
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```